# Game lagging when AVAudioPlayer plays

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm creating a game where the user controls a character with a jetpack. When the jetpack intersects a diamond, I add the diamond to their total and then play a sound. However, the sound makes the game pause for a tenth of a second or so and disrupts the flow. This is the code I'm using:

```
var diamondSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("diamondCollect", withExtension: "wav")!
var diamondPlayer = AVAudioPlayer?()

    class GameScene: SKScene{

      override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

            do {
                 diamondPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: diamondSound)
                 guard let player = diamondPlayer else { return }

                 player.prepareToPlay()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                 print(error.description)
            }
       }
```

And then later:

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        if character.intersectsNode(diamond){
            diamondPlayer?.play()
            addDiamond()
            diamond.removeFromParent()
        }

    }
```

Also I am using Sprite Kit if that matters. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would try and use `SKAudioNode` or `SKAction.playSoundWithFileNamed` first since they are built to be used with SpriteKit.  Also,  you do not need the guard since you are doing a try catch,  I would remove it.  if a nil is returned from AVAudioPlayer, it will fire the catch

Comment: The issue I am seeing, is you may be firing play multiple times,  add a check to only play once, AVAudioPlayer has a `playing` boolean you can  check

Comment: Just because you remove diamond from the parent, does not mean diamond is dead,  your intersectsNode will still pass even if diamond is not on the scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Using `SKAction.playSoundWithFile` worked great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anyway you can test my play being called multiple times theory?  This way I can write a proper answer for you (Switch to SKAction is not answering the question, and somebody else may come across your issue looking for an answer with AVAudioPlayer)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I did not change anything with the multiple times theory. It worked well with the first solution and nothing else was required.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I prefeer to use `SKAction.playSoundWithFile` in my games but this one have a limitation, there is no volume setting.
So, whit this extension you can solve this lack:

```
public extension SKAction {
  public class func playSoundFileNamed(fileName: String, atVolume: Float, waitForCompletion: Bool) -> SKAction {

    let nameOnly = (fileName as NSString).stringByDeletingPathExtension
    let fileExt  = (fileName as NSString).pathExtension

    let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(nameOnly, withExtension: fileExt)


    var player: AVAudioPlayer! = AVAudioPlayer()
    do { player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundPath!, fileTypeHint: nil) }
    catch let error as NSError { print(error.description) }

    player.volume = atVolume

    let playAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }

    if(waitForCompletion){
        let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(player.duration)
        let groupAction: SKAction = SKAction.group([playAction, waitAction])
        return groupAction
    }

    return playAction
  }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("diamondCollect.wav", atVolume:0.5, waitForCompletion: true))
```

Comment: Why would you go through this trouble,  use SKAudioNode like I have mentioned in the comments.  There are tons of problems with your approach (Which is the same as the OP, thats why I told him to switch)  one of which being if you pause the sprite, your audio will still play

Comment: This is not a trouble , this is one of the many approaches you can use (SKTAudio library is another for example). First of all there are no lagging so answer to the OP question, second you must distinguish your audio between background music, effetcs. Obviusly, an extension cannot be do the Audio Manager of your game. It's bette to maintain the player references and more than one player. An action can be launched not only from the sprite involved. This method can be used to little effects cannot reasonably do not need to pause, otherwise you can improve it to enable a pause if you want.

Comment: There is lag, your audio is not prepared until after the run block occurs,  it may not lag the game, but the audio itself will be delayed.  My point is you are creating an extension that does what SKAudioNode does, but poorly.  SKAudioNodes can behave almost as identical as actions,  but instead of adding an action to a node,  you are adding a child  Here is what it comes down to,  You can take this free bucket to go get your water and is known to  hold it, or you can use your resources to build your own bucket and risk it shooting out leaks because you may have missed a step

Comment: Let's be realistic, SKAudioNode is available only from iOS 9, I cannot accept a solution with the minimal iOS requirement as the 9, it's too early. So, IMHO SKAudioNode is not still acceptable.

Comment: Let's be realistic,  not many people < 9 will be using the app store to download new games,  too many new games out there require it.  Plus, apple harasses the user until they update.  iOS 8 is almost 2 years old, so it reasonable to expect iOS 9 right now.  Statistically,  you are alienating like 15% of iOS users,  and most of these are the people that use the phone as a phone and bare basic machine, not as an app device.

Comment: LOL I agree with you about Apple (it's fantastic "harasses the user") and personally I like SKAudioNode, but not to publishing .Explain me why Pokemon Go it's available for iOS 8.0,Clash Royale it's available for iOS 7.0 !!! Candy Crash for iOS 5.1.1, I can continue but it just to understand..

Comment: Those games are not built on Sprite Kit,  they are built in things like Unity that allows for cross platform development.  Do not be comparing apples and oranges here

Comment: I'm speaking about the market, money, obviusly these titles are titans but this is the market and this is only bussiness opinions, thank you for pleasant and interesting discussion, I've appreciated as always.

Comment: oh I know,  do the research on what devices are doing what,  there is a plethora of information out there.  You will see that the cost in development time may not be worth the potential target you are reaching (Kind of like spending $10 to make $1).  The only reason why candy crush is built for iOS 5.1.1 is because the game engine was built for it, and pokemon go is for iOS 8 is because whatever they use to develop has a library for iOS 8.